# Using Counter on a list of Spacy tokens returns a non unique dict of the tokens

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, counter, spacy

I want to count a list of spacy tokens with the counter class. I.e.:

```
[hello,how,are,you,hello]
```

where each element is of type `<class 'spacy.tokens.token.Token'>`.
However when i want to count the  occurences of each Token within the list via counter, as seen below:

```
    return Counter(joined)
```

The result is a **non unique dict of the tokens** or in other words: the same list as before but its a dict now and each key has the value of 1. In the screenshot below it can be seen, that the dict seemingly has the same key twice in it.

[image]

What is the reason  for this?

Comment: Please add a code snippet so everyone can reproduce the result!

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are not equivalent if they have the same text, they have to be in the same position in the same Doc object. But the output in your screenshot (don't post a screenshot of text...) is just the `repr` of a token, which is its text.

If you want to count just the text, use `token.text`, like so:

```
from collections import Counter
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc = nlp("this is text, this is text")
out = Counter([tok.text for tok in doc])
```